# How to make a transparent layout?

Tags: java, android

I have following code for main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I need that the LinearLayout will be transparent. I thought that I can do it using the alpha setting in a background attibute, but it doesn't work. Please, tell me - I need that my application will be empty and has a white rectangle on the center of a screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the activity to be transparent? 
Try using this theme in your activity tag (in the manifest file): `@android:style/Theme.Translucent`

For other possible ways, ie child theme see the following answers:

[Activity should be transparent, but has black background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687712/activity-should-be-transparent-but-has-black-background)

[How do I create a transparent Activity on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android)

[how to make activities transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562004/how-to-make-activities-transparent)

Answer (score 0):

Use below line in the xml file:

```
<Linearlayout android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
```