# Cannot set PopupWindow background to transparent

Tags: android, background, android-mapview, transparent

I have the following code:

```
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.contextual_menu_lp_activity, null)   
child.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));
child.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
popup = new PopupWindow(MapViewActivity.this);
popup.setContentView(child);
popup.showAtLocation(MapViewActivity.mapView, Gravity.CENTER, 10,10);                           
popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());                          
child.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                    popup.update(50, 50,child.getMeasuredWidth(), child.getMeasuredHeight());
```

As you may see, I set the view, and desperately try to make its background transparent.

On the xml layout, all the relativelayouts are given a transparent color background.

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/transparent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/ivDialogPopup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:paddingBottom="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/new_pop_up_bk" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btLivePolice"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btSaveParkingLocation"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/live_police_button_popup" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btSaveParkingLocation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/parking_location_button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btGetDirections"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btSaveParkingLocation"
    android:background="@drawable/directions_button" />
```

Still, the view's parent layout(a relative layout) still has a gray background.
(Previously, I was using the normal activity class and in the manifest i had a transparent theme -the most important part of it was setting this android:windowBackground to transparent- I have to change it for a different reason).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So, what is the issue? I do not see a question or problem stated.

Comment: @prolink007 sorry, the popup window is still showing a gray background, consistent with the parent relativelayout of the view.

Comment: Can you post your xml file, it will aid in solving this issue.

Comment: @prolink007 posting right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you do is create a transparent png (eg. clear.png) file and place it in your drawables folder, then call

```
yourPopUp.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.clear));
```

This way the popup is still dismissible, which is not the case if you try to use null.

Comment: setBackgroundDrawable takes a drawable as param

Comment: I accidentally forgot the getResources.getDrawable()

Answer (score 24):

You can also set background transparent like below. This Worked for Me.

```
popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Comment: so simple... Thanks!

Comment: @MarkDelphi You are welcome. Glad it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `@android:style/Theme.Translucent` for your `RelativeLayout` instead of changing the `background` color.

[Here are some other suggestions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663916/how-to-make-a-transparent-layout)

Comment: Still not working unfortunately. I have tried the suggested fix. It does better than the original: the parent layout is transparent. However, the image background is now no longer showing, and something gray is put in its place - but only over the image background, not over the entire layout!

Comment: Could you possibly draw the desired layout. Expressing which parts you are wanting transparent and which parts you are not wanting transparent? I am having difficulty understanding your desired layout.

Comment: I managed to fix it. I will post the results asap on SO, with explanations as well.

Comment: Cool, looking forward to seeing what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: So, what was the solution?

Comment: @LKallipo Never got around to it, but I will today or tommorow.

Answer (score 0):

Use android:background="@null"