# How to show an alert dialog without activity background

Tags: android

I am creating notification using below code.

```
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Don't forget", System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.defaults|=Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.defaults|=Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
        notification.defaults|=Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(Create_notification.this,After_alarm.class);
        intent2.putExtra("arr", arr);
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(Create_notification.this, 0,intent2 ,0 );
        nm.notify(i, notification);
```

I want to show some string on alert dialog after clicking on notifiction.For doing this I created Alert dialog in the oncreate() of the activity(i.e After_alarm activity) but this is showing the background of After_alarm activity and an alert dialog on it.I Only want to show alert dialog.Is their is a way to make an activity visible like alert dialog.I also changed theme of After_alarm of activity to alertdialog but dis is not wat I want.It is occupying a large space of screen. 
Plz help me
thnx

Comment: You can make your activity transparent and show Alert Dialog on top of it.

Comment: Can you plz tell me how to make activity transparent

Comment: Please see the answer. It has links to what you've asked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I said in the comment, you can make your activity transparent and show Alert Dialog on top of it. See answers [How do I create a transparent Activity on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android) and [how to make activities transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562004/how-to-make-activities-transparent) for how to make it transparent. Hope it helps.

Comment: not a good practise as it will occupy the whole screen and without the user pressing back, the user will think there phone is not responding to on clicks and touches as its invoking onTouch on  a transparent activity

Comment: @jonney Thanks for the comment. Why wouldn't it allow the user to press back? The device's back button will be visible. One can handle the back button pressed in the transparent activity as well. One can also have `onTouchListener` outside the `AlertDialog` in the transparent activity. Inside that listener they can close the activity. Can you please mention more as you what you are trying to say in your comments? Maybe I am not understanding it right. Thanks.

Comment: I mean the user has to press back to dismiss the invisible activity. Imagine if u unlock your phone and you are presented with your home screen and onTouch doesnt work? it will frustrate the user as he or she wont know that a invisible activity is present on the screen.

Comment: @jonney I understand your concern. It is not like that the user would "only" see a blank transparent activity. The OP wants to show an `AlertDialog` from the transparent activity. So it won't be completely blank just overlaying over user's UI (that won't make sense at all). When there is a dialog and user anyway can touch outside your dialog and close the activity as well as I explained in the second part of my previous comment. Hope that helps.

Answer (score -3):

You could use `.setVisibility(View.GONE)` which will work fine.

```
alertdialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```